# PHP $_SESSION id with random number

Tags: php, session

So I'm trying to set an id for each person that uses my order page. So if they want to order 2 things the `requestid` stays the same.

```
if(empty($_SESSION['requestid'])) {
    $requestcode = sprintf('%05d', rand(0, 99999));
    $requestid = '210'.$requestcode;
    $requestid = $_SESSION['requestid'];
}

echo 'Request id : '.$requestid.'<br>';
```

So what im doing wrong?

Comment: sessions are user unique ... so jsut use that?

Comment: It saves to my database with that number and later it makes bills with that bill id..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$requestid = $_SESSION['requestid'];
```

**Just flip your variable**

```
$_SESSION['requestid'] = $requestid ; // this will set requestid into session
```